# Computing dual spaces with canonical identification

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have a question regarding an identification that my professor taught me that apparently is useful to the identify the dual space of a normed space. My notes say:

> $X$ can be seen inside the bidual space of $X$ with the map $J:X \to
>  X^{**}$ such that $x \mapsto J_x$ where $J_x:X^* \to \mathbb{K}$ is
>   such that $J_x(f) = f(x)$. The completion of $X$
>   is given by $\overline{J(X)}$.

Apparently, my professor uses this identification to compute the dual space of $c_0$ with the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ norm. He sets the following:

$\tau:l_1 \to c_0^*$ such that $\{\alpha_n\} \mapsto \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \alpha_n\beta_n$

and then proves that this is an isomorphism between the normed spaces.

So my question is the fact that $X$ can be seen inside the bidual space seems obvious. But:

1. Why the completion of $X$ is $\overline{J(X)}$.
2. What are the rigurous steps to arrive to the $\tau$ from this natural identification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather easy to determine that  $\ell_1^*=\ell_\infty$; if $f:\ell_1\to\mathbb C$ is linear and bounded, it follows immediately that 
$$
f\left(\sum_j \alpha_j\,e_j\right)=\sum_j\alpha_j\,f(e_j).
$$
It is not hard to check from here that $\{f(e_j)\}\in\ell_\infty$, and that every $x\in\ell_\infty$ induces a functional by $\alpha\longmapsto \sum_j\alpha_jx_j$. So, under that identification, $\ell_1^*=\ell_\infty$.

Since $c_0\subset\ell_\infty$, this suggests defining $\tau$ as your prof did. After you prove that $\tau $ is an isomorphism, you know that $c_0^*=\ell_1$, and so $c_0^{**}=\ell_\infty$.

The equality $\overline{J(X)}=X^{**}$. Note that the closure is in the weak$^*$-topology. The proof of the equality is a rather easy exercise.